# Как узнать всякий цифровой адрес что есть параметр у всякого серверного компьютера?

Tags: веб-программирование, ip, домен

Как узнать всякий цифровой адрес что есть параметр у всякого серверного компьютера? IP address а не URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nslookup yandex.ru
dig A yandex.ru
ping yandex.ru
```